# Retrieve values of prediction in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, predict

Is there anyway i can store in variables (to use in an `if` condition later) the values i get after using `model.predict_on_batch()`?

For example, my problem got 3 outputs, and i got this result:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=1159525, shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[ 2.0149750e+03,  1.2258940e+03, -1.5718406e-01]], dtype=float32)>
```

So, would be something like:

```
y1_pred = 2.0149750e+03
y2_pred = 1.2258940e+03
y3_pred = -1.5718406e-01
if y1_pred < 3000 and y1_true < 3000:
   print("Ok!")
else:
   print("Not ok!")
```

Comment: The numbers are there, you just need to index the output, like y1_pred = out[0] and so on

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro sorry, but what do you mean by out? I haven't defined anything as "out". I got that result from the command `model.predict_on_batch(test_input)`. I'm not sure how to index those outputs from the tensor to a variable.

Comment: out = model.predict_on_batch(test_input), y1_pred = out[0][0]